# React access const outside of block scope

Tags: reactjs, scope, constants, block

Hi I am trying access a const which is assigned a value within the block scope of componentDidMount() and assign it within a different method but I am having difficulty achieving so. I have tried saving it to state, however 'something' is not defined within renderTable()

My code is as follows:

```
// Pseudo code:
class tableView extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    .......
      const something = 'blah';
      this.setState({something});
  }
  renderTable() {
    const tableData = [
      {
        name: 'Item 1',
        data: this.state.something,
      },

    ];

    return {
        ......
    };
  }
```

Are there any other approaches to allow me access the something const within renderTable()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
state = {
tableData : [
      {
        name: 'Item 1',
        data: this.state.something,
      },

    ],
 something:'this is something on mount it will change to blah',

}


 componentDidMount() {
.......
  const something = 'blah';
  this.setState({something});
}

  renderTable() {
   const {tableData} = this.state;

    return {
        ......
    };
  }
```

access with `this.state.tableData` or use destructuring.

Comment: Sorry didn't have a chance to accept until today. Thanks very much, that solved it!

Answer (score 3):

Note that the reason that you're getting `not defined` error is because you have not yet initialized the component's `state`. If you were to `console.log(this.state)`, the value will be `null`. So you're trying to access `.something` out of `null`, which will not work.

In React, stateful components must have their state initialized. One way of initializing the state is in the constructor (check the link posted below).

```
class App extends React.Component {
    // THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE MISSING!
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          something: '',
        }
    }
    // END

    componentDidMount() {
        const something = 'blah';
        this.setState({ something });
    }

    renderTable() {
        const tableData = [
          {
            name: 'Item 1',
            data: this.state.something,
          },
        ];

        return ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Read https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html (Ctrl+F 'constructor') for more information.